# edit_bones not defined

Tags: python

```
import bpy

print("_____________________")

list_obj = []
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    for vg in obj.vertex_groups:
        list_obj.append(vg.name)
        
set_obj = set(list_obj)

armature = bpy.data.armatures["Armature"]

for bone in armature.bones:
    print(bone.name)

for bone in armature.edit_bones:
    print(bone.name)
    if bone.name not in set_obj:
        print(bone.name)
        edit_bones.remove(bone)
```

This code gives

> NameError: name 'edit_bones' is not defined

How can this happen?

Comment: last line `edit_bones` change to `armature.edit_bones`

Comment: I would strongly advise against doing that. You'll be removing items from a list while iterating over it, which is a big no-no in programming. You need to create a copy of `armature.edit_bones` before iterating over it (usually adding `[:]` does the trick)